# In my CSV file, it shows I have 1 column when I actually have 15 columns

Tags: r

```
> df <- read.csv("DATA ONLY.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

> dim(df)

 [1] 439 1
```

This is the code I use and this is the CSV

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOqDKXZ7BAMW5LdqBcBIvQE9_PnFcNIHDfYDty3cTto/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure you have `sep = ';'` ? Maybe it it just comma. Try `df <- read.csv("DATA ONLY.csv")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure that you have defined the field separator wrong. `data.table::fread` is really good at sniffing the correct format of csv's, and I quite often use fread even if I just convert the resulting data.table back to vanilla data frame, i.e.

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("DATA ONLY.csv")
as.data.frame(df) -> df
```